# CSS Grid Bug with long words in Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari, css-grid

I have two examples for a card with two columns of the same width.
The upper card is implemented with flexbox. The lower card with grid.
In Safari, however, the grid example pushes the left column to the width of the word.

Only when I add word-break: break-word;, the word is wrapped.
Why does the Safari handle the breaks differently? Is there a workaround?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
}

.flexcard {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.flexcard > * {
    width: 50%;
}

.gridcard {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h2 {
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
font-size: 3rem;
}

.safari-fix {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" lang="de">
  <div class="flexcard">
    <h2>Wirstschaftswissenschaften</h2>
    <p>
      this is some Copytext. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridcard">
    <h2>Wirstschaftswissenschaften</h2>
    <p>
      this is some Copytext. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridcard">
    <h2 class="safari-fix">Wirstschaftswissenschaften</h2>
    <p>
      this is some Copytext. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks in Safari browser. In all other browsers, the wordbreak is in all examples correct:

[image: Screenshot from Safari Browser]

Comment: I'm really not seeing the difference, can you explain the question a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "word-break: break-word;" you can use "text-overflow property"
which is clipped the text and display an ellipsis (...) Or you can simply use custom string. (If you don't want ellipsis)

```
    white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: That is also a good alternative. However, I want the word or words to be completely visible, they just have to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested in Safari and one simple fix would be to change your `grid-template-columns` like so:

```css
.gridcard {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Or better yet change it to `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%)` and it'll be easier to maintain if you need to change the number of columns in the future.

If you want a `gap` property, you'll have to account for that by dividing the gap width by however many columns you have and subtracting that from the 50% assignment:

```css
.gridcard {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, calc(50% - (1rem / 2));
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

As to why Safari behaves this way, I'm not sure.  Could be a bug in Safari related to grids or frs or `-webkit-hyphens`, could be Safari interpreting a vague CSS specification in a way that no other browser does.  Both happen reasonably often lol.  If anyone knows specifically why, please comment and I'll update my answer.

That said, it would also be fine to just use `word-break: break-word` if that makes things work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately 50% will have a conflict with the gap porperty.

Comment: @kimomat You're right—I've updated my answer to address that.  Let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: That would be an alternative for this example code. However the above sample code is a simple example. In my project i can't switch from fr to percent.

Comment: @kimomat Ah, understood.  If you feel like explaining why that is, I'd be happy to keep trying to figure something out, but ultimately `word-break: break-word` might be your easiest solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. I already use the Safari fix via word-break: break-word in the code example. However, I would be interested to know why Safari does not recognize the hyphens.